# How to make stay logged in when app not running in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I build some app from Ionic V1 and I want to make user stay logged in for 12 days. My problem is how to make logged in user will be discovered when the user opens the app after the user closes app? I'm new in Ionic and angular js, can you help me to solve my problem

thanks

Comment: What you mean by user in 12?

Comment: i mean loggen in 12 days

Comment: You can use cookie for that. Set expiry time in cookie

Comment: i try simple cookies like this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies but i stiil understand how to make redirect to stage home if logged in

Comment: For example appCtrl is main controller so here you have to check cookie value if is_login so you have to redirect to home page otherwise on login page

Comment: you have simple example ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145505/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-rizka-nugroho).

Answer (score 2):

you can use `jwt token` storage functionality in localstorage to check.

like :

> step 1 : when user login get the token and store it in local storage.
>
> step 2 : check for this token every time when the app open

for eg :

when app open and first app controller run first, then emits the function in this controller to check if localstorage have token ?

if **no**, go to login page, login and save the token, then go to app functionality.

if **yes**, go directly to the app functionality (rather render login page )

> step 3 : for every logout remove the token.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON Web Token for user session maintenance in which you can store user identity data and also set expiration time for the token, and user specific data can be fetched from server using this token.
This token can be stored in Local Storage.

For more information, refer here [JWT](https://jwt.io/)